# what is the name of this sorting algorithm? is it bubble sort? most easy sorting?

Tags: python, sorting

what is the name of this sort? its just like bubble sort but its easy to write but harder in term of complexity.codes are in python language.

```
def sort(arr): 
    n = len(arr) 
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if arr[i] < arr[j] : 
                arr[j], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[j]
```

but bubble sort is like this :

```
def bubbleSort(arr): 
    n = len(arr) 
  
    # Traverse through all array elements 
    for i in range(n): 
  
        # Last i elements are already in place 
        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 
  
            # traverse the array from 0 to n-i-1 
            # Swap if the element found is greater 
            # than the next element 
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1] : 
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
```

Comment: It's a variant of selection sort, although usually the inner `j`loop would be over `range(i+1, n)`.

Comment: bubblesort or selection sort ? or it is just youruselesssort ?

Answer (score 4):

It is neither selection sort nor bubble sort, but an unnecessary bad sort. All of them, your sort, selection sort and bubble sort are of the same complexity, O(n^2).

Your sort sweeps over the array in two loops without consideration for if an element has reached its proper place (as in selection sort) or if an element has gained a place relative to the next (as in bubble sort). The extra code in bubble and selection sort make them far better than yours.

Compare, yourself:

```
def sort(arr):
    print(arr)
    n = len(arr) 
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if arr[i] < arr[j] :
                arr[j], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[j]
                print(arr)

def selectionsort(arr):
    print(arr)
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n-1):
        min_index = i
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if arr[j] < arr[min_index]:
                min_index = j
        arr[i], arr[min_index] = arr[min_index], arr[i]
        print(arr)

def bubblesort(arr): 
    print(arr)
    n = len(arr) 
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1] :
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
                print(arr)

print("sort:")
sort([4,6,3,2,7,1,8,5])
print("selectionsort:")
selectionsort([4,6,3,2,7,1,8,5])
print("bubblesort:")
bubblesort([4,6,3,2,7,1,8,5])
```

with the results:

```
sort:
[4, 6, 3, 2, 7, 1, 8, 5]
[6, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1, 8, 5]
[7, 4, 3, 2, 6, 1, 8, 5]
[8, 4, 3, 2, 6, 1, 7, 5]
[4, 8, 3, 2, 6, 1, 7, 5]
[3, 8, 4, 2, 6, 1, 7, 5]
[3, 4, 8, 2, 6, 1, 7, 5]
[2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 1, 7, 5]
[2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 1, 7, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 8, 6, 1, 7, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1, 7, 5]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 2, 7, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 3, 7, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 7, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 6, 7, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
selectionsort:
[4, 6, 3, 2, 7, 1, 8, 5]
[1, 6, 3, 2, 7, 4, 8, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 8, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 8, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 8, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
bubblesort:
[4, 6, 3, 2, 7, 1, 8, 5]
[4, 3, 6, 2, 7, 1, 8, 5]
[4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 1, 8, 5]
[4, 3, 2, 6, 1, 7, 8, 5]
[4, 3, 2, 6, 1, 7, 5, 8]
[3, 4, 2, 6, 1, 7, 5, 8]
[3, 2, 4, 6, 1, 7, 5, 8]
[3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 7, 5, 8]
[3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 5, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 5, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

It doesn't make a big difference on small arrays but on large arrays it make a lot of difference (but then there are other methods).