# What type of sorting algorithm it will be called?

Tags: sorting

What type of sorting algorithm will it be called if I don't find the minimum value (like selection sort), instead I find the element smaller than the current element and swap.

```
def sort(list):
    n = len(list)
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(i+1, n):
                if list[i] > list[j]:
                    tmp = list[i]
                    list[i] = list[j]
                    list[j] = tmp
    return list
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: There are already many questions on Stack Overflow, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63214115/what-is-the-name-of-this-sorting-algorithm-is-it-bubble-sort-most-easy-sorting), which answer this question. Actually if you search for something like ["what sorting algorithm is this"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+%5Bpython%5D+what+sorting+algorithm+is+this) then about half of the existing questions asking to identify a sorting algorithm are about this algorithm.

Comment: @GSerg It's not bubble sort; it's an inefficient variation of selection sort.

Comment: Thank you @kaya3.

I was confused whether it was a variation of bubble sort or selection sort.
I got my answer now.